# How to get the index of duplicated values, while dropping NAs? Resulting index is smaller than original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a df:

```
df.shape[0]

82208
```

And I want to index duplicates based on firstname, lastname and email:

```
indx = (df.dropna(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'])
       .duplicated(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'], keep=False))


indx

0         True
1         True
2        False
3        False
4         True
5         True

indx.shape[0]

73797
```

I am unable to use this against the original df using `df[indx]` as they do not match in size as you can see from `.shape[0]`. I tried to use `indx.index` also, but I get:

```
df[indx.indx]

KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([    0,     1,     2,     3,     4,     5,     6,     7,     8,\n                9,\n            ...\n            82198, 82199, 82200, 82201, 82202, 82203, 82204, 82205, 82206,\n            82207],\n           dtype='int64', length=73797)] are in the [columns]"
```

I know it's something very simple, I just can't figure it out. It seems the `indx` I generate resets its index. What I'm trying to get is an index of where there are dupes in the first df. I'm guessing my problem has something to do with the `dropna()` when generating the index.

edit: It was suggested to check out a duplicate post, but this doesn't answer my question.The duplicate is just basic indexing.

My problem is that in generating the new index / boolean series `'indx'`, the original `df` indexes are lost. So it can't be used to index the `df`.

**edit:** another solution for this is reindexing so it matches the size of the df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'firstname':['stack','Bar Bar',np.nan,'Bar Bar','john','mary','jim'],
                   'lastname':['jim','Bar','Foo Bar','Bar','con','sullivan','Ryan'],
                   'email':[np.nan,'Bar','Foo Bar','Bar','john@com','mary@com','Jim@com']})

print(df)

  firstname  lastname     email
0     stack       jim       NaN
1   Bar Bar       Bar       Bar
2       NaN   Foo Bar   Foo Bar
3   Bar Bar       Bar       Bar
4      john       con  john@com
5      mary  sullivan  mary@com
6       jim      Ryan   Jim@com


indx = (df.dropna(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'])
                 .duplicated(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'], keep=False))

indx = indx.reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)


df[indx ]

  firstname lastname email
1   Bar Bar      Bar   Bar
3   Bar Bar      Bar   Bar
```

Comment: do you want `df.loc[indx]` ?

Comment: Yes that would be good. I tried that but getting errors.

Comment: one more thing, if you dont want nan values, why not return it as `False` instead of dropping them: `indx=(~df[['firstname', 'lastname', 'email']].isna().any(1)& 
 df.duplicated(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'], keep=False))`

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work, just doing a quick check it in a csv. can you figure out any reason why my version didn't work?

Comment: So in that case its not a dupe. If you can confirm, I will post an answer (prob with your version is `.dropna()`- you loose out on indexes which is not a good way when doing a boolean indexing

Comment: Hi @anky_91, your version works for me. Checked the CSV and they are all duplicates which is the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dropping the nans and then creating the boolean mask, add to the boolean mask that returns False for `nan` so you have all indexes retained, but false for nans. using `df.isna()` and `df.any()` for `axis=1` we can use the below:

```
cols=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email']
index=(~df[cols].isna().any(1)&df.duplicated(subset=cols, keep=False))
```